# How to schedule a `lint` error (update: use papercut)

Tags: android, gradle, continuous-integration, lint, release-management

I'm looking for a way to temporarily suppress a `lint` error or to schedule an error after a particular date or condition.

Here's some context:

*I have an android app that is translated to multiple languages and I have set it up so that `lint` fails with an error if there are missing translations. Evidently this is done so that untranslated strings don't escape into the wild.
Whenever there's a new `string` resource, it takes a while until it gets translated, during which `lint` fails.
This can be suppressed or the strings can be marked as untranslatable but that beats the purpose of having the check in the first place.*

Aside from that context, there are plenty more instances when a particular setting is "temporary". I don't like having to remember to flip back every switch.

The builds are on a CI server, releases are often and this happens in a team where anyone is able to "temporarily" ignore warnings.
Is there an automagical way to make sure things don't get ignored upon release?

**Update:**
Since asking this question, someone has developed a library that does just what I asked and more: https://github.com/Stuie/papercut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you determin when it is time to de/activate lint. But maybe this helps:
You can switch Lint on/off with a boolean in the gradle script:

```
android {
  lintOptions {
   if (lintOn){
     checkReleaseBuilds true
     abortOnError true
   } else {
     checkReleaseBuilds false
     abortOnError false
  }
 }
}
```

Add `lintOn=false` to your gradle.properties, otherwise gradle won't recognize it as variable.
Now you cann add a task and make it run before the build task:

```
task preBuild << {
    // do stuff to determin if lint should run
    lintOn = true
}
build.dependsOn preBuild
```

In this preBuild task you can now implement some code to check if you should run lint or not. 
[Here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html) are some good examples of what a task can do.